# Compute $\gcd(5^{202} + 1, 5^{74} + 1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to compute this greatest common divisor? I don't want the final answer, just a tip of how to begin, because I'm stuck in this problem.

Comment: Clearly the gcd will be even.

Comment: probably intended 5^222

Comment: (Possibly a ) tip : I ...... guess you gotta divide and equate the GCD of the remainder and the divisor to that of the divisor and the dividend ?

Comment: As proved in the linked dupe, if $\,b,c\,$ are odd and coprime then $\,\gcd(a^b+1,a^c+1) = a+1,\,$ so $\,\gcd(25^{101}+1,25^{37}+1) = 25+1\ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $202-74 = 128$, so we can try to subtract off $5^{202}$ and reduce the problem like this:

\begin{align}
&\gcd(5^{202} + 1, 5^{74} + 1)
\\ =\,&\gcd(5^{202} + 1 - 5^{128}\cdot (5^{74} + 1), 5^{74} + 1)
\\ =\,&\gcd(5^{202} + 1 - 5^{202} - 5^{128}, 5^{74} + 1)
\\ =\,&\gcd(-5^{128} + 1, 5^{74} + 1)
\end{align}

now you can continue reducing

Comment: Should it be $-5^{128}$ or there's another step that I am missing?

Comment: @peterwhy you are right, I made a mistake